# Открыть файл через программу Python

Tags: python, файлы

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как передать и обработать имя файла в программу написанную на Python?
Например: `python text.txt program.py`

Comment: Погугли в сторону модуля argparse

Answer (score 1):

Самый простой способ:

```
import sys


print(sys.argv[1])
```

И передаем аргумент при запуске скрипта:

```
python program.py text.txt
```

Comment: Спасибо, разобрался :)